# Display size and format

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

In my VCL form application I have added:

1. Button
2. OpenDialog
3. Edit
4. ListView

When I open a file with opendialog, how do i display the file size and format in ListView column?

Here is the code which am trying - please correct my mistake, or what function do I have to add to display in ListView?

```
//===============================
procedure TForm1.BntOpen1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LI: TListItem;
begin
   if OpenDialog1.Execute then
     LI := ListView1.Items.Add;
    LI.SubItems.Add(Format(OpenDialog1.FileName, [0]));
end;
//===========================
```

thanks

Comment: Please help us by making your question much more clear. That will involve spending some time explaining in more detail what you are stuck on. Also, "n" is not a word.

Comment: What's missing is a OpenDialog. Then write some code in the button click handler.

Comment: I edited the code formatting for you. If you include also the type definition of your form, you can delete your list of what components you have.

Comment: Sorry friends for my bad English.. But now I have  edited my question.I hope you guys will understand .

Comment: @Tom if you don't mind can you post your code .

Comment: That is not how SO works, we are not a code writing service. But answer the following: Why is there a `TEdit`. Read up in [Delphi reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Delphi_Reference) compound statements, (or code blocks (`begin ... end;`)) and about the `Format()` function.

Comment: @Tom sorry I didn't add a lines in my code. TEdit is for displaying the file which I choose from a directory.//...edit1.text:=opendialog1.filename;...//I know am not good in coding as you guys i make mistake alot because am just a learner so my humble request is to help or guide me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are missing a `begin .. end;` pair.

```
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then 
  begin  // missing
    // ...
    // fetch file size and update `TListView` here
    // ...
  end;  // missing
end;
```

Then to get the file size, declare a variable `size: int64;` and use a `TFileStream`

```
var
  size: int64;
...
    fs := TFileStream.Create(OpenDialog1.FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
      size := fs.Size;
    finally
      fs.Free;
    end;
```

Be sure to read up on **file mode and sharing** constants

Have you used the `Column Designer` of the listview to declare the columns you need?
If not, right-click on the `TListView` and select `Column Designer`from the menu.

You correctly added an item to the listview but you never assigned a caption to it, so I would assign the filename, so it would be clear to which file the size and type are related.

```
  LI.Caption := OpenDialog1.FileName;
```

Then you add the size of the file into a subitem

```
  LI.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(size));
```

and finally the file type

```
  LI.SubItems.Add(ExtractFileExt(OpenDialog1.FileName));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your great help .Now its working as I want it  really you are awesome...thank you.

Comment: @meitei Glad I could help. Now, I can see that you have not yet visited [**the tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) which describes in short terms how the SO site works, please do so. And also take a look at [**what should I do if somebody answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: am new user to this apps that's why i make mistake but now I came to know by your advice. In future I will try not to make mistakes and to follow as you said.